# Wordpress - Alphabetically Order Taxonomies (get_taxonomy)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code outputting the categories I have into a drop-down. I'm trying to alphabetically order these categories in the drop-down to make it easier for my users to find them.

```
<?php // output dropdown for each taxonomy //
  foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) { ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $tax . '_cat'; ?>">
  <label for="wppl-category-id"><?php echo get_taxonomy($tax)->labels->singular_name; ?>: </label>
  <?php custom_taxonomy_dropdown($tax); ?>              
</div>
<?php } /* end foreach */ ?>
```

I looked it up and it seems that get_taxonomy has no orderby options (at least that I could find). Is there any suggestions for how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: does this help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/change-order-of-custom-taxonomy-list

Comment: You are not showing here the code of the query, you are showing result after query is executed. try posting the query and follow reikyoushin advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can check the native function [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)?

it has an orderby argument and i believe you can order them by name.

there is an example there, so if you just replace count into name you will get this:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' );
```